# Remove spaces from variable writelines in C#

Tags: c#

My current code is meant to get an output resembling something like "The enemy is south east" but currently with the way ive set up the writeline it ends up writing stuff like "the enemy is north________west" ("_" representing the spaces) with a lot of spaces, I'm aware it is caused by how I've formatted the {0}, {1} etc. but idk how else to do it, is there a way I could get a clear cut "north west" with only one space in between

my code:

```
class Program
    {
        public static bool north;
        public static bool south;
        public static bool west;
        public static bool east;
        public static string coordinates;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insert Coordinates:");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (x < 0)
            {
                west = true;
                east = false;
            }
            else if (x > 0)
            {
                west = false;
                east = true;
            }
            else if (x == 0)
            {
                west = false;
                east = false;
            }
            if (y < 0) 
            {
                north = false;
                south = true;
            }
            else if (y > 0) 
            {
                north = true;
                south = false;
            }
            else if (y == 0)
            {
                north = false;
                south = false;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The enemy is {0} {1} {2} {3}", north ? "north" : "", south ? "South" : "", east ? "east" : "", west ? "west" : "") ;

        }
    }
Blockquote
```

Comment: Move the spaces? `Console.WriteLine("The enemy is {0}{1}{2}{3}", north ? "north " : "", south ? "South " : "", east ? "east " : "", west ? "west" : "") ;`

Comment: Unrelated: This is superfluent `else if (x == 0)` . If x is neither smaller than nor greater than 0 , then you already know what it is.

Comment: Though Fildor's answer is probably the "thing to do" here, you're question how to remove multiple whitespaces can also be solved by using Regex: 

`Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("The enemy is {0} {1} {2} {3}", north ? "north" : "", south ? "South" : "", east ? "east" : "", west ? "west" : "", @"\s+", " ");`

Comment: what if instead of inserting empty commas if direction = false you put null? So that it insert actually nothing in there? Or just remove the false condition from the `Console.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 2):

You shoot yourself into the foot as you have four variables but those variables aren't independent and rely one one another. So when `north` is `true`, `south` cannot also be `true`. The same applies to `west` and `east`. So instead of having four variables, you could omit two of them:

```
string xDir = x < 0 ? "west" : x > 0 ? "east" : "";
string yDir = y < 0 ? "south" : y > 0 ? "north" : "";
```

Now in order to prevent spaces when any value is empty, you could trim the strings a bit:

```
var output = $"The enemy is { (xDir + " " + yDir).Trim() }";
```